# Play - Json deserialization of data type Map[X,List[Y]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a variable with `Map[models.Account,List[models.Journal_account]]` type..

I dont know how to deserialize that data type. Usually I use below code :

```
implicit val Account_detailWrites: Writes[Account] = (
    (JsPath \ "account_code").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "account_name").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "account_type").write[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "description").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "enable_payment").write[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "expense_claims").write[Boolean]
)(unlift(Account.unapply))

implicit val Account_detailReads: Reads[Account] = (
    (JsPath \ "account_code").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "account_name").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "account_type").read[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "enable_payment").read[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "expense_claims").read[Boolean]
)(Account.apply _)
```

Since it has List[Y], I don't know what to do..  Can anybody help me here ?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks guys for your answers, but I already used jerkson to create a Json response..
Example: `Ok(generate(variable_name)).as(application/json)`

Comment: What would this look like in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to define `reads` and `writes` for your `models.Journal_account` class.

e.g.

```
implicit val journalAccReads: Reads[JournalAccount] = ..
implicit val journalAccWrites: Writes[JournalAccount] = ...
```

and then

```
implicit val Account_detailReads: Reads[Account] = (
(JsPath \ "account_code").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "account_name").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "account_type").read[Int] and
(JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
(JsPath \ "enable_payment").read[Boolean] and
(JsPath \ "expense_claims").read[Boolean] and
(__ \ "journalAccounts").lazyRead(list[JournalAccount](journalAccReads)))
)(Account.apply _)
```

and similar entry for accountDetail `Writes`

btw, Scala/Java recommends camel case `val` , `var` names.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Json Objects have `String` keys. The default `Reads` definition from Play works for `Map[String, V]` where `V` has a `Reads[V]`, not any `Map[K, V]` even if `K` has a `Reads[K]`.

Can you return an `account_name` in the `Map` instead of the entire `Account`?